# Indicating a method argument in java doxygen comment

Tags: java, doxygen

I'm investigating if there is a way to indicate in the doxygen comment of a java method, that you are referring to a method argument. Basically I've found `<h>` or `@a h` or `@p h` to indicate that `h` is a method argument (see examples below). Is there any difference / recommended way to indicate a method argument?

```
/**
 * Set height to @a h
 */
function setHeight(int h) {
    this.height = h;
}

/**
 * Set height to <h>
 */
function setHeight(int h) {
    this.height = h;
}

/**
 * Set height to @p h
 */
function setHeight(int h) {
    this.height = h;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly but how about @param

Comment: I want to be able to tag the method argument within the general description or @brief description. I'm not referring to the seperate paremeter description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `@a` and `@p` will do the trick nicely and are equivalent. `<h>` is not something doxygen supports.

Comment: Is one of the two depreciated?

Comment: no, I added both to be more compatible with other doc tools.